# how to remove duplication from a CSVfile by making some checks?

Tags: python

I have a CSV like:

```
col-1(ID)       col-2(val-List)

1               [1]
1               [1,2,3]
2               [1,2]
2               [1]
3               [10]
3               [10]
```

and I want to remove duplicate from this file and at the end, I just need a single row which has greater list length, like:

**edited:**

**I want to keep a single row if there are those rows which have the same ID and same length of the inner list.**

```
col-1(ID)       col-2(Val-List)

1               [1,2,3]
2               [1,2]
3               [10]
```

I tried a lot but no luck:
I'm giving try by using CSV module but do not have an idea that how should I maintain the length of previous **Val-List** and compare with next matching ID.

```
import csv 
list_1 = []
with open('test123.csv', 'r', encoding='latin-1') as file:
    csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csvReader:
        key = (row[0])
        # but how should I use this id to get my desired results?
```

Comment: Are you sure you want ',' as delimiter? This way it splits also on the commas which are inside your col-2(val-List)

Comment: Yeah, comma delimiter. I tried by checking the inside list which is Val-list. so far it's  good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not let `pandas` do the work?

```
import pandas

# Read in the CSV
df = pandas.read_csv('test123.csv', encoding='latin-1')

# Compute the list lengths
df['lst_len'] = df['col-2(val-List)'].map(lambda x: len(list(x)))

# Sort in reverse order by list lengths
df = df.sort_values('lst_len', ascending=False)

# Drop duplicates, preserving first (longest) list by ID
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='col-1(ID)')

# Remove extra column that we introduced, write to file
df = df.drop('lst_len', axis=1)
df.to_csv('clean_test123.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure this performs the logic to keep only the row that has the longest `col-2(Val-List)`? As I understood this is what OP wants.

Comment: yeah I want to keep the row which has longest col-2(Val-List)

Comment: I tried this and its working but now having one exception which i haven't explained above.

Comment: can you please check the edit and suggest me a solution in above script?

Comment: Not sure what the exception is - even if the lists have the same length, this will retain one of them if the IDs match. What is the exact corner case this misses?

Comment: getting an error that "float object is not iterable".

Comment: That probably means that your dataframe has not been constructed properly, most likely due to the default comma delimiter. Does your file only have comma spacing, not tab or anything else? You can inspect `df.head()` after reading in the CSV to check whether you have only two columns; I suspect you do not. Either read in with a different delimiter (if your file has another option) or you'll have to do  join all the columns together so that you have a stringified list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183906/discussion-between-gigabyte-and-rvd).